# Dos ecuaciones relacionadas

Tags: python

Tengo dos ecuaciones que están relacionadas entre sí, y necesito hallar algunos de sus parametros por medio de la libreria scipy.optimize, pero no sé como puedo hacerlo.
Que función puedo usar para hacer lo anterior? 
Alguna sugerencia? Agradezco la ayuda.
Por ejemplo:

```
X=cosB+c*d y Y=2*d + c*senB.
```

Donde conozco los valores de X y de Y, y necesito los de las otras variables.
Como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Las incógnitas son `B`, `c`  y `d`? En ese caso veo dos ecuaciones y tres incógintas, lo que apunta a que no hay solución única.

Comment: Hola, que sucedería en el caso de que no sean tres incognitas sino solo 2?, por ejemplo B y c. Gracias